# I got SQLiteException in greendao : failed to change locale for db

Tags: android, crashlytics

Crashlytics shows me exception that failed to changed locale for db caused by SQLiteDatabaseLockedException it shows database is locked.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

To:

```
myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS
```

Comment: DBOpenhelper class is used can you tell me what to do in this scenario?

Comment: Can anyone tell me if I am using DbOpenHelper class then what is the solution for that?